# I cannot understand the meaning of EclipseLink MOXy XmlProperty or xml-property, could anyone give more information?

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

What I can find on google are ONLY 3 piece of information, and the most detailed is the design doc as following URL

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/DesignDocs/317962/Phase2.1#.40XmlProperty

It does mentioned that "The xml-property metadata tag will be used to configure a property." and two examples without marshaling results are given as following:

```
Example: type-level property
The following example will demonstrate how a type-level property can be applied.

Setting xml-property on a type via EclipseLink XML metadata can be accomplished as follows:

<java-type name="org.example.Employee">
    <xml-properties>
        <xml-property name="identifier" value="101" value-type="java.lang.Integer" />
        <xml-property name="isTrue" value="false" value-type="java.lang.Boolean" />
    </xml-properties>
</java-type>
Setting @XmlProperty on a type via annotations can be accomplished as follows:

org.example.Employee.java
@XmlProperties({@XmlProperty(name="identifier", value="101", valueType=Integer.class), 
                @XmlProperty(name="isTrue", value="false", valueType=Boolean.class)})
public class Employee {
   ...
}
Example: property-level property
The following example will demonstrate how a property-level property can be applied.

Setting xml-property on a property via EclipseLink XML metadata can be accomplished as follows:

<java-type name="org.example.Employee">
    <java-attributes>
        <xml-element java-attribute="myelement">
            <xml-properties>
                <xml-property name="isAttribute" value="false" value-type="java.lang.Boolean" />
                <xml-property name="comment" value="this is an element" />
            </xml-properties>
        </xml-element>
    </java-attributes>
</java-type>
Setting @XmlProperty on a property via annotations can be accomplished as follows:

org.example.Employee.java
public class Employee {

  @XmlProperties({@XmlProperty(name="isAttribute", value="false", valueType=Boolean.class),
                  @XmlProperty(name="comment", value="this is an element")}
  public String myelement;
}
```

I also tried my example, but I cannot tell any difference between with and without the xml-property stuff.

Can anyone explain to me what does XmlProperty do? What kind of effects does it produce? or When to use XmlProperty? Is there any sample code with marshaling results?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED">
        <xml-ns prefix="ns1" namespace-uri="http://www.example.org/customer" />
        <xml-ns prefix="ns2" namespace-uri="http://www.example.org/phone" />
        <xml-ns prefix="ns3" namespace-uri="http://www.example.org/addr" />
    </xml-schema>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="example.gettingstarted.demo1.Customer">
            <xml-root-element />
            <xml-type namespace="http://www.example.org/customer"
                prop-order="name address phoneNumbers" />
            <xml-properties>
                <xml-property name="hello" value="false" value-type="java.lang.String" />
                <xml-property name="world" value="this is an element"
                    value-type="java.lang.String" />
            </xml-properties>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-attribute java-attribute="name" xml-path="@name" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="address">
                </xml-element>
                <xml-element java-attribute="phoneNumbers" xml-path="contact-info/phone-number" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="example.gettingstarted.demo1.PhoneNumber">
            <xml-root-element />
            <xml-type namespace="http://www.example.org/phone"></xml-type>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-attribute java-attribute="type" />
                <xml-value java-attribute="value" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="example.gettingstarted.demo1.Address">
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Java Files:

```
package example.gettingstarted.demo5;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

import example.gettingstarted.demo1.Address;
import example.gettingstarted.demo1.Customer;
import example.gettingstarted.demo1.PhoneNumber;

/**
 * @author barry
 * make Customer.Address.street as Customer.@street
 */
public class Demo {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        // Step 1 - Create the Domain Model
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Jane Doe");
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setStreet("123 Any Street");
        address.setCity("My Town");
        customer.setAddress(address);
        PhoneNumber workPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
        workPhoneNumber.setType("work");
        workPhoneNumber.setValue("613-555-1111");
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(workPhoneNumber);
        PhoneNumber cellPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
        cellPhoneNumber.setType("cell");
        cellPhoneNumber.setValue("613-555-2222");
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(cellPhoneNumber);

        // Step 2 - Convert the Domain Model to XML
        final Map<String, Source> metadataSourceMap = new HashMap<String, Source>();
        metadataSourceMap.put("example.gettingstarted.demo1", new StreamSource("./example/gettingstarted/demo5/eclipselink-oxm.xml"));

        final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, metadataSourceMap);

        final Class[] classes = new Class[1];
        classes[0] = Customer.class;

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = (JAXBContext) JAXBContext.newInstance(classes, properties);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }
}
```

And my output is as following, no matter whether the xml-property is applied.

My Town
          123 Any Street
       
       
          613-555-1111
          613-555-2222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s `@XmlProperty` extension is a way to get custom data into MOXy's native mapping metadata.  It is for some pretty unique use cases.  I will demonstrate how this can be used below.

**JAVA MODEL**

I'll use the following model for this example.

```java
package forum15651379;

public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**DEMO CODE**

In the demo code below the `JAXBContext` will be bootstrapped on MOXy's external mapping document (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html).

```java
package forum15651379;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum15651379/oxm.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar("Hello World");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**COMMON USE CASE**

Below is the typical use case.  Mappings are defined with the `java-attributes` element.

**oxm.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum15651379">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Foo">
           <xml-root-element name="FOO"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="bar" name="BAR">
                </xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FOO>
   <BAR>Hello World</BAR>
</FOO>
```

**ADVANCED USE CASE**

**oxm.xml**

I have expanded the `oxm.xml` to include properties and have specified a descriptor customizer.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum15651379">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Foo" xml-customizer="forum15651379.FooCustomizer">
            <xml-properties>
                <xml-property name="key1" value="value1"/>
                <xml-property name="key2" value="value2"/>
            </xml-properties>
           <xml-root-element name="FOO"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="bar" name="BAR">
                    <xml-properties>
                        <xml-property name="key3" value="value3"/>
                        <xml-property name="key4" value="value4"/>
                    </xml-properties>
                </xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Descriptor Customizer (FooCustomizer)**

A descriptor customizer gives you access to MOXy's native mapping metadata.  Below is a trivial example of what you could do with the properties specified in the `oxm.xml` file.

```java
package forum15651379;

import org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping;

public class FooCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer{

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
        XMLDescriptor xmlDescriptor = (XMLDescriptor) descriptor;
        String key1Value = (String) xmlDescriptor.getProperty("key1");
        xmlDescriptor.setDefaultRootElement(key1Value);

        XMLDirectMapping barMapping = (XMLDirectMapping) xmlDescriptor.getMappingForAttributeName("bar");
        String key3Value = (String) barMapping.getProperty("key3");
        barMapping.setXPath(key3Value + "/text()");
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below we see the impact of what we did in `FooCustomizer` on the resulting XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<value1>
   <value3>Hello World</value3>
</value1>
```

Comment: Thank you Blaise! I really appreciated your answer and the neat demo. I like MOXy really, especially the runtime dynamic metadata driven style. It would be the first choice for a key component inside a multi-tenant platform.

Comment: @BarryZhong - Thanks Barry.  We have developed MOXy with multi-tenancy in mind.  Here is a link to an example you may find interesting:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/moxy-extensible-models-multi-tenant.html

Comment: Yes, that's really cool. I had read and tried most of the MOXy examples from wiki.eclipse.org. I do tried that example, and I found it is multi-tenant in nature, that's just what I want. Thank you Blaise for what you did for the world, I envy you.